# JSON data handling from PHP array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am using an AJAX request to dynamically fetch some data from a database. The data is returned back to AJAX after being put through the PHP function `json_encode()`. The returned value that I recieve from the AJAX request is as follows:

```
{"counter":1,"1":{"objectID":"1","objectType":"note","objectDate":"2015-10-10     19:55:26","objectTitle":"Test Note","objectContent":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecetur adpiscing...","objectColor":"white"}}
```

How would I go about splitting this data down into separate variables such as `counter` for where the `{"counter":1` JSON object is? Also, how would I split the sub-arrays of the JSON data into individual javascript arrays?

All help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just set the `dataType` to `json` and it does that automagically ?

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is set `dataType` to `"json"` in your `ajax` call then pass the result with `success` like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'example.com',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
        console.log(json);
    }
});
```

[From the jQuery.ajax() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> **dataType:**
>
> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript
>   object. Cross-domain "json" requests are converted to "jsonp" unless
>   the request includes jsonp: false in its request options. The JSON
>   data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and
>   a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also
>   rejected; the server should return a response of null or {} instead.
>   (See json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.)

Answer (score -1):

With a simple:

```
JSON.parse(data);
```

I have managed to achieve this.
Couldn't find this when originally researching.

Comment: Why would you need to parse the result as json when it's already parsed automatically by `ajax`?